# How to configure pytest to save stdout into a file?

Tags: pytest

I'm writing a pytest test suite that tests data from an external API. The tests look something like this:

```py
def test_call_specific_method(api):
    result = api.call_specific_method()
    print(result)
    assert data_is_good(result)
```

This is a very simplified version. Due to the architecture of the tested code, **I would prefer to use `print` statements instead of the `logging` module**.

**How can I configure pytest to capture `stdout` contents during test runs and save them into a file?**

I tried configuring `log_file` and `log_level` in `pytest.ini` according to [the docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/logging.html#live-logs).

```ini
[pytest]
log_file = logs/pytest-run.log
log_level = INFO
```

However, this solution appears to only work with `logging` calls, while regular prints do not get captured.